# linux ramdisk - Sync to disk

Tags: linux, ramdisk

I have configure a ramdisk to optimize access to a few log files.
Is there a way to keep a constant copy of the ramdisk to a physical disk?

I would like to avoid loosing everything after a power loss and have to rebuild the system from scratch.

Comment: _"I have configure a ramdisk"_ - how? Tell us everything that seems related to the question. Use the [edit] feature to add it to your post.

Comment: Have you considered a UPS battery backup?  Then when power goes out your can do a proper shutdown before the battery runs out.

Answer (score 3):

There is - but be careful what you wish for!

If you chose such a setup will of course have the write-performance (latency and bandwidth) of the slower, real disk. It is however convenient if you want to optimize for read performance.

Here are the steps:

- Prepare the disk partition you want to use as a backing file
- Prepare a ram-disk as a block device, i.e. if you just use `tmpfs` create a backing file and `losetup -f` to it
- create a RAID1 of those 2: `mdadm --level 1 --raid-disks 2 /dev/mdX /dev/ram/backing/device -W /dev/disk/backing/device`
- Mount the resulting MD device and use it

This way your writes will go to both disks, but your reads will mostly be satisfied by the RAM disk (because the real disk is marked as `-W` or "write-mostly")

Answer (score 1):

Using a "proper" disk-backed filesystem will do that for you - it will optimize access to the files on it by buffering the data in RAM. If you modify the data, it will first modify the data in RAM, then it will wait for a bit and finally write it to the disk.

In other works, exactly what you want to do manually.

You can tweak the I/O scheduler kernel parameters per block device to ensure more aggressive buffering if that is what you need - but first measure if you really need it.

Comment: Not for the large batches. F.ex. I want to compile project as fast as possible. That is ~1 Gb of written data. No filesystem will write-delay such amount of data. Then I want to rebuild it after a while. With filesystem there is no guarantee it is still kept in buffers, so non-modified objects will be read from disk.